90 degree elbow on speedy valve
I'm changing vanity and the speedy valve unfortunately is too high and preventing me from installing the faucet hose.
I don't want to touch this speedy valve.

Is it OK to install a 90 degree elbow to allow me to install the faucet hose horizontally?
The opening of the speedy valve is 1/2 inch, so would something like an elbow work?

The linked elbow will not work because it is pipe thread; the threads on your "speedy valve" (also known as an angle stop valve) are compression threads which were originally meant for use with tubing connections (before the advent of flex supply lines).
There aren't a lot of fittings that have female compression threads; it could be easily cobbled together using multiple fittings but that would likely take up more space than you have.
The best option here is to tighten that valve an extra 1/4 turn. Or remove and reinstall at a more optimal position. I know you don't want to touch it... but it's really not that complicated. Shut off the supply if you are worried about it.

Thank you very much, I didn't know the threads were different. I found a compression thread elbow, will give it a try. The speedy valve is not turning with reasonable force so I'd like to avoid touching it.

@igorjrr   All threaded plumbing connections need the use of two wrenches.  One to turn and one to hold the other piece from turning.  Turning a solid mounted pipe is not good when loosing or tightening a fitting on.

Then take it off, clean the threads with a brush, apply new tape and reinstall it to the required orientation. You don't solve this problem with more parts and connections. That's counterproductive.
